# Unable to use session in Laravel

Tags: session, laravel-5

I'm just creating a simple login page in Laravel 5. 
Problem: After successfully login I have to create a session of email address and move to dashboard. If session is not created than move to login page.

Here is my controller function code:

```
public function admin_auth()
{       
    $matchThese = ['email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' =>     $_POST['password']];
    $login['result'] = DB::table('login_auth')->where($matchThese)->get();

    if($login['result'])
    {
        //session_start();
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $_SESSION['session_email'] = $_POST['email'];
        Session::put('session_email', $_POST['email']);
            if (Session::has('session_email'))
            {
                 echo 'Done';
            }else echo 'Session Not Created';           


    }else echo 'Email Or Password Not Match';
}
```

In above function I got 'Done'.It means the session is created but when I'm checking same variable in other method of the same controller then session is not set.

Here is my other function:

```
   public function dashboard()
    {  
         if (Session::has('session_email'))
                {
                    return view('login.dashboard');
                }else echo 'Session Not Created';    

    }
```

I always got 'Session Not Created'.

Thanks for help in advancd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using version 5.2

You should include all routes using sessions within a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) group called `web` which is defined in `Namespace\Http\Kernel` under `$middlewareGroups`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Routes using sessions

});
```

Comment: Yes I m using Laravel 5. New in Laravel framework can u plz tell me what exactly i should write in routes.php.

Comment: Just move every route you have defined into the code block I have posted above